# How to set Home page title in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, title

I have created a separate blog from an already existing blog. I have changed site and home url. I have also changed the blog title. But I am not able change the title showing in the home page. Its showing the name of old blog (copied blog). Can anyone suggest me how to change the title?

Answer (score 4):

If you use the WP plugin All in One SEO Pack, and then go into the **plugin's** general settings, that should work.  We had the same issue and wrote a pretty detailed blog post about it: [Change Title of a Wordpress Home Page](http://www.debi-z.com/2011/08/04/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-my-home-page-in-wordpress/).

Comment: Include content in post please. Links die.

Comment: Well then StackOverflow gets credit for the detailed instructions instead of the author. And they answered the question anyway.

By the way, now the All-In-One SEO Pack's editing functions appear at the bottom of the edit screen for every Page and that's where you can set the title if you want it to be different.

Comment: That blog post doesn't seem to be available anymore. For me, the problem was solved when I changed the change-title option in the All in One SEO options to deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at admin > appearance > editor? then checking header for the title tag and seeing if you or someone else change the title to the old blog name? If not then I'd suggest doing so and changing it to `<title><?php wp_title(' '); ?></title>`

Comment: From where its taking the title value? Can we change it in database.

Comment: Changing the title value in setting is good enough. I do not think you have to go into the database to change anything. I think you have an issue with your theme. An easier way to check would be to change your theme and see if the title still stands.

Comment: Hi I have changed the blog title in general settings. I have also tried by hard-coding the title in the header file. I have tried changing the theme. But no change in the home page title :(

Comment: Do you have a plug-in such as Search Engine Optimizers or something that would force a title change?

Comment: I agree that it sounds like an SEO plugin is overriding the title... Disable all plugins that seem to have to do with SEO and I bet the new title you have set in your General Settings will finally appear.